# Understanding XLR phantom power adaptor

Tags: microphone, adapter, device

[image]

It's a scheme for microphone adapter, from XLR to mini-jack, with the conversion of 48V phantom power to plug-in power 6.2V. Could you describe how the circuit works?

Comment: Please describe the device in the title.

Comment: I don't know the XLR pinout from head: What is 1,2,3 in XLR? (1 is probably going to be ground).

Comment: Yup, 1 GND, 2 is non-inverted, 3 is inverted. At what level is the explanation necessary, because it is as simple as it can possibly get - the phantom power from XLR is dropped to 6.2V for biasing the TRS mic. Also audio is coupled via capacitor back from TRS to XLR.

Comment: pins 2 and 3 have 48 V on them from the PP source, the 172k resistor and the 6.2 V zener form a shunt regulator to give 6.2 (ish) V, 50 V capacitors for a 48 V supply is sailing a bit close to the wind, I would go 63 at a minimum.

Comment: @Justme I see how the Zener is operated in saturation; will that not effectively absorb a relevant amount of signal, seeing that the signal will be an oscillation around 6.2V potential, a region where the the Zener is a low impedance path to ground? (i.e. the microphone raising the voltage slightly above the zener voltage will lead to a super-proportional change in current through the Zener) My gut demands an inductor in series with the Zener, but then we get into a lot of transient problems on plugging in and out...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Good catch, you are absolutely right. If the mic does not use enough current in order to drop voltage below zener, zener will clamp the audio too. No need for inductor though, typically mic bias is applied via around 2k resistor. So at this point, I don't see how that circuit can ever work.

Comment: @Justme it probably simply still does – mic amps are sensitive as hell, and the nonlinear distortions "well, you're using a cheap microphone with studio equipment, what were you expecting"

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you are right on that too. Well, that is as good as random unreliable internet schematics can get. Especially with a name like "ProTips", that does not look very "Pro" to me.

Comment: @Justme one of us should put these results in an answer, though I don't really feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: that zener's going to be a noise source :(

Comment: @Justme you didn't, so I had to write that answer ;) also, I've adopted Jasen's comment.

Comment: https://sound-au.com/articles/mic-electret.htm If you really want something that actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long answer short: that circuit will badly work, and in general, youtube is (on average) a really bad source for electronics.

So, the idea is relatively simple:

Phantom power is a constant voltage thing. So for that, wherever there's a capacitor, replace it with an "open". The circuit simplifies to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foc8lX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not that the microphone looks like a capacitor to DC, too, as long as there's silence, so we'll ignore that for now. I'm still leaving it in the schematic so it's easy to remember where we look at the current.

Because when it comes to the phantom power, both the inverting and non-inverting XLR contacts 2&3 are at the same potential, so that further simplifies to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9VBQl.png)</sup>

which can be simplified to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJfnU.png)</sup>

which simplifies to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxMd4S.png)</sup>

And that's basically it: there's an 48 V source, in series with a Zener diode. The Zener diode works as a classical Zener shunt regulator, i.e. if you increase the voltage across it even slightly above its Zener voltage 6.2 V, a huge additional amount of current can flow, and since that current can only come out of the 48 V supply at XLR 2 & 3, and has to flow through 188 kΩ or resistance, there will effectively be a pretty stable 6.2 V across D1.

And thus, across the Microphone.

Small problem:

A microphone works by *varying the amount of current that flows*; conversely, it will try to lower or raise the voltage across D1.

But D1 has a low resistance for any signal above 6.2 V. That's why we're having it in the first place. So, pretty much exactly half of the output of the microphone will be badly attenuated by this circuit, simply because all positive voltages "added" by the microphone atop of the phantom bias will be "swallowed" by the diode.

We call that a *nonlinear distortion*, because the output is not a linear function of the microphone signal.

These are hugely unpopular in music recording, because they change the spectrum of what the recording end sees.

Another thing that is hugely unpopular in music recording is adding electronically caused noise. And a Zener diode in breakdown is an excellent noise source; in fact, the typical white noise source for 50's to 80's music (think the rain in "[riders on the storm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G2-FPlvY58)" by The Doors) is really just a reverse semiconductor junction (in a transistor, or actually in a Zener diode like yours).

So, don't build this circuit, unless you want to sound like someone in a darth vader helmet in the rain. (This is an exaggeration. But you're definitely not making much of your fine electret microphone if this is how you power it.)

Comment: So, what circuit would you suggest?